# ROS2 Ubuntu 22.4 No module named 'rclpy._rclpy_pybind11'

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, ros2

when i start create and run my first node in ros2 humble i have some problems , i try to fix them by i change default python version 3.10 down to 3.8 but it doesn't work
this is my problems and my code ,thanks
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucVji.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRe5g.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOxuF.png)

No module named 'rclpy._rclpy_pybind11'